# As of 2016-June - Which companies are registered with the NYC Bitlicense?

Tags: regulation, financial-regulations, bitlicense

As of today 2016-June - Which companies are registered with the NYC Bitlicense? I heard that only 2 were given these licenses while everyone else is just waiting. Why and how did these few select companies get this license so easily vs everyone being held back?